# What is it called when you use array syntax for form field names?

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

When creating forms one can use the PHP `[]` array syntax to have multiple form fields populate an array when the input is parsed in PHP, like this:-

```
<input type="text" name="myArray[]">
<input type="text" name="myArray[]">
```

What would you call these kind of fields? *Array input fields*, maybe?

**Aside:** the PHP docs for this type of form input can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays)

Comment: The [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays) just calls them "arrays sent from a form".

Comment: array of input elements with the name "myArray"

Answer (score 0):

It just like a normal input form. But value to send is multiple value, therefore it just set like array type